# Count the status messages in a column VBA

Tags: vba

Can someone review my code and provide feedback. For context in column A will be a status message of "OK" or "NOK" and this little function just counts the number of times this appear so I can update a label in another procedure. Not too sure if this is the most efficient way of doing this because looping will create delay going row by row if the data set is very large as in the main procedure this function will be called to update the label is in a loop so depending on the size of the data it can be small or very large and will trigger this function for each row.

```
Function UploadStatus(ByRef WS As Worksheet, ByVal StartRow As Long, ByVal EndRow As Long, Optional ByVal strMsg As String) As String
Dim OK As Long
Dim NOK As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim uploadMsg As String
 
If StartRow = 0 And EndRow = 0 Then Exit Function
With WS
    For i = StartRow To EndRow
        If .Range("A" & i).value = "OK" Then
            OK = OK + 1
        Else
            If .Range("A" & i).value <> vbNullString Then
                NOK = NOK + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
 
If OK < 2 Then
    uploadMsg = OK & " OK row, "
Else
    uploadMsg = OK & " OK rows, "
End If
 
If NOK < 2 Then
    uploadMsg = uploadMsg & NOK & " NOK row"
Else
    uploadMsg = uploadMsg & NOK & " NOK rows"
End If
If strMsg <> vbNullString Then
    UploadStatus = strMsg & " " & uploadMsg
Else
    UploadStatus = uploadMsg
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would not worry about the pluralizing and use `row(s)` in the message. The `iif` can be used to simplify the code.

```
Function UploadStatus2(ByRef WS As Worksheet, ByVal StartRow As Long, ByVal EndRow As Long, Optional ByVal strMsg As String) As String
    Dim Target As Range
    With WS
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Target = .Range(.Cells(StartRow, "A"), .Cells(EndRow, "A"))
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Function
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Dim OK As Long, NOK As Long
    
    With WorksheetFunction
       OK = .CountIf(Target, "OK")
       NOK = .CountIf(Target, "NOK")
       UploadStatus2 = .TextJoin(" ", True, strMsg, OK, "OK", "row" & IIf(OK > 1, "s", ""), ",", _
       NOK, "OK", "row" & IIf(NOK > 1, "s", ""))
    End With
    
End Function
```

Comment: thanks I think this is the most elegant way of combining everything and also efficient thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Your homemade function will *never* be as fast as the built in functions.

```
Function UploadStatus(ByRef WS As Worksheet, ByVal StartRow As Long, ByVal EndRow As Long, Optional ByVal strMsg As String) As String
  Dim OK As Long
  Dim NOK As Long
  Dim uploadMsg As String
 
  If StartRow = 0 And EndRow = 0 Then 
    Exit Function
  End If
  
  OK = WorksheetFunction.CountIf("A" & StartRow & ":A" & EndRow, "OK")
  NOK = WorksheetFunction.CountIf("A" & StartRow & ":A" & EndRow, "NOK")

  uploadMsg = ResultStringer(OK & "OK")
  uploadMsg = uploadMsg & ResultStringer(NOK & "NOK")
 
  If strMsg <> vbNullString Then
    UploadStatus = strMsg & " " & uploadMsg
  Else
    UploadStatus = uploadMsg
  End If

End Function

Private Function ResultStringer(ByVal Count As Long, ByVal ID as String) as String

  If Count > 1 Then
    ResultStringer = Count & ID & " rows, "
  Else
    ResultStringer = Count & ID & " row, "
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: I got type miss match and object required errors from your answer when I tested it. I posted a modified version fixing the errors below for completeness. Thanks for the suggestion using countif.

Comment: It was "air coded", so that's not surprising. Glad you go it working. Be sure to click the check-mark of the answer that helped you the _most_

Answer (score 1):

This is a refined solution based on the answer above as I found few errors when testing like type miss match and object required.

```
Function UploadStatus(ByRef WS As Worksheet, ByVal StartRow As Long, ByVal EndRow As Long, Optional ByVal strMsg As String) As String
Dim OK As Long
Dim NOK As Long
Dim uploadMsg As String
 
If StartRow = 0 And EndRow = 0 Then
   Exit Function
End If

 With WS.Application.WorksheetFunction
    OK = .CountIf(Range("A" & StartRow & ":A" & EndRow), "OK")
    NOK = .CountIf(Range("A" & StartRow & ":A" & EndRow), "NOK")
End With
uploadMsg = ResultStringer(OK, "OK")
uploadMsg = uploadMsg & ", " & ResultStringer(NOK, "NOK")
 
If strMsg <> vbNullString Then
   UploadStatus = strMsg & " " & uploadMsg
Else
   UploadStatus = uploadMsg
End If
 
End Function
Function ResultStringer(ByVal Count As Long, StatusID As String) As String
 
  If Count > 1 Then
    ResultStringer = Count & " " & StatusID & " rows"
  Else
    ResultStringer = Count & " " & StatusID & " row"
  End If
```